# JPA: Check duplication of non-id fields before persist / merge

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to refactor an old service project, where the underlying database is being accessed by different parties, so I am not free to alter the data structure.
The project's code is a wild mix of Hibernate and direct database access right now, which I want to bring into a homogenous JPA implementation.

Right now, I am facing the limits of my understanding of the JPA inner workings and would like to find some clarification and/or best practices for the following problem:

I have a Transition entity as follows (stripped to the interesting parts):

```
Transition
  id
  oldStatus
  newStatus
```

When saving a Transition, the client provides IDs for both the new and the old state (which is another entity's id). Each transition is to be stored with a generated id. As the combinations of oldStatus and newStatus are supposed to be unique, the code right now does something like this:

```
Result r = query(select * from Transition where oldStatus='?' and newStatus='?')
if(r == null)
   persist
else
   use id of r
```

If I understand the inner workings correctly, Hibernate does not regard the hash()/equals() methods, but only the @ID field in order to decide whether an entity does exist or not. As the client doesn't know the IDs of the Transitions, but only the old and new state of the model, it cannot provide the ID up front. Is there any way to make Hibernate/JPA check other fields than the @ID annoted field?

The Transition entity is used several times in another entity and updating that entity would require to check the values of the Transitions provided by the client against the existing Transitions in the database and update the id in the provided entity, before passing the entity to the persist/merge mechanism.

Is it possible to configure the entity in a way that Hibernate will be able to connect the correct Transition when persisting/merging?

Comment: Why not use oldStatus and newStatus as composite ID fields instead then?

Comment: The transition id is used as a foreign key in another table, I guess that's why this layout has been chosen. I thought about the composite ID too, but I am not sure how JPA would link that enity in the other table.

Comment: Something will need to change then to stay with pure JPA, as it does not allow referencing through non-pk fields.  Either your model should hold onto the ID, or the ID changed.  Hibernate and others do allow foreign keys to reference non-pk fields, but it sometimes hurts performance as it means the cache/identity map is harder to use to resolve those references.